# Infragistics UltraTimeLineView allow scrolling when control is disabled

Tags: winforms, scroll, infragistics, disabled-control

I've an Infragistics UltraTimeLineView. I'm not showing the horizontal scrollbar because I don't need it, but I do need the vertical scrollbar.

In some cases I need to disable my control to avoid the user to add appointments or remove, resize, drag or edit the created ones. The problem is that I want that the user still be able to see all the created appointments, and that is not posible because I've too many Owners.

Increasing the shown-owners in the grid is not a possibility.

Thanks for your help! Diego

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible.

[Question in Infragistics forum](http://community.infragistics.com/forums/t/55714.aspx).